# What's the difference between "double* grade", "double *grade", and "double* fn()"?

Tags: c++, pointers, variables

Pointer variables are confusing to me. Consider the code below:

```
int main() {double* grade; double *grade;}

double* fn() {}
```

What is the difference between `double* grade` and `double *grade`?
What is the difference between `double`, `double*` in `int main()`, and `double*` of `fn()`?

Comment: There is no difference between `double* grade;` and `double *grade;`

Answer (score 4):

These are the same:

> ```
> double* grade;
> double *grade;
> ```

Both define a variable of type `double*`. These are also same:

```
double*grade;
double * grade;
double    *   grade ;
double
*
grade
;
```

In many cases, white space is optional in grammar of C++. Note that your program is ill-formed, since there are two variables defined with the same name in the same scope.

> ```
> double* fn() {}
> ```

This is definition of a function that returns `double*` and has empty argument list. This particular function has undefined behaviour because there is no return statement despite the function not returning `void`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between `double* grade;` and `double *grade;`

`double* grade;` defines a pointer to double.

`double grade;` defines a variable of type double.

`double* fn();` declares a function that returns a pointer to double